# My DataGridView properties window went blank!

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, datagridview, properties

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 w/.NET 2.0.  I have no idea what happened, but all of a sudden I noticed that the Properties window for ALL of the DataGridViews in my project went blank.  I've tried dropping in new ones..still blank.  I restarted Visual Studio and my computer...still blank.  I've done some google searches, and I've found people who have had the same problem, but there is no solution and it appears that Microsoft has been unable to duplicate it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project in a new instance of Visual Studio and dropped a DataGridView in there, and it worked..then I checked my other project in the other instance of VS and the Properties can back for my DataGridViews.  Fluke or solution?  No idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems where my property windows go blank. It tends to happen when your machine is using a lot of UI resources or your toolbox is trying to update its list of controls.

1. Check to see if your control is being selected by your property window at the top of the property window screen
2. Try switching to a different control and then back to force the property window to update
3. Just close your UI Designer and re open it.
4. If all else fails, just close and reopen your solution

If it's still a problem you can always reduce how much memory your toolbox/UI designer uses by removing custom control generation in your toolbox window. To do this go to Tools / Options / Windows Form Designer / AutoToolboxPopulate - set to false. Now this will not populate your toolbox with custom controls anymore from your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This same thing happened to me because the full path of the project contained an '&'.  When I moved the project to a path that did not have an '&' everything worked.

There was same problem - reason was '&'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bunch of similar problems with Visual Studio UI doing wacky things. I figured it had to do with memory consumption (not a lack of machine memory). Jetbrains made a wrapper [here](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/OutOfMemoryException+Fix) that has solved a lot of my problems in Visual Studio 2005.